# How to click on hidden field - Selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to automate logging and put user name in hidden field and I have the following simple code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\geckodriver.exe')    
driver.get("https://timeoff.guru/to/company/timeoff.nsf")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="username"]').send_keys('user')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]').send_keys('pass', Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="select2-searchMember-container"]').click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/span/span/span[1]/input').send_keys('user', Keys.ENTER)
```

Everything works good except last Keys.Enter which doesn't execute.

Comment: Can you post your full code, as well as full error trace, as well as full html of that page (which cannot be accessed without a login)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire, this is the entire code and no errors when is executed. I try to attach the html but its more than 30000 lines and SO refuse it. I tried to attach jpg but I don't have permission to upload pictures.

Comment: If send keys doesn't update the hidden field's value, then you'll need to execute javascript to change the value attribute.  Enter key can't be pressed on a hidden field though.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium was designed to work as a user would which means that it can't (without workarounds) operate on hidden elements. The workaround in this case would be to use JavaScript.

NOTE: This is not advised because you are manipulating the page outside of what a normal user would be able to do and are bypassing any number of things like validations, etc. that the page has in place to avoid bad inputs, etc.

But... without the actual page link, we can't advise you on the proper way to do this.

Using JS, your last line would be replaced with the lines below

```
input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/span/span/span[1]/input')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value='user'", input)
// now you need to click on Submit or whatever the button is to proceed
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my issue. Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='D:\selenium\geckodriver.exe')

driver.get("https://timeoff.guru/to/company/timeoff.nsf")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="username"]').send_keys('user')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]').send_keys('pass', Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[11]/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/span/span[1]/span/span[2]').click()
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/span/span/span[1]/input')
elem.send_keys('user')
sleep(5)
elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```